# Eclipse does not recognize that Glassfish stopped

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, shutdown

I am currently encountering the following issue:

I am using a Glassfish 3.1 Server to deploy my applications on and am frequently restarting him from within Eclipse to have a clean Glassfish (he sometimes keeps some old classfiles and I just want to make sure...)
That should be working fine, but every ~5 times restarting the server it wont start up again. The log output looks like this:

```
INFO: Server shutdown initiated
INFO: JMX002: JMXStartupService: Stopped JMXConnectorServer: null
INFO: JMX001: JMXStartupService and JMXConnectors have been shut down.
INFO: Shutdown procedure finished
```

After this no more lines are printed out. I already tried to wait for some time but it wont start again from itself.

Meanwhile Eclipse is constantly showing "Restarting Glassfish 3.1 at localhost" in the Prograss View. If i click the stop button it only turns gray but wont vanish. Also telling the server to start up again is not working as it waits for the "restarting" to finish and well... that isnt happening.

To still be able to work I have to restart Eclipse every time the Glassfish server wont stop...

I can work with it, but am interested if anyone has experienced similar behavior and maybe even has a solution :)

## Edit 1

Forgot to include that I am using Eclipse Keppler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've installed the latest version of the Glassfish Tools from Oracle.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/index.html

Comment: Installed the whole tools and thereby updated the glassfish tools but nothing has changed..

Comment: Hey after i restarted my computer and added a new Server (was for a different reason) this worked for me ^^ so thanks

Answer (score 0):

My eclipse base version is:
Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)

I had this problem also.
Removing, then re-adding the Glassfish server instance did the trick for me. Nothing else required.